# If p is prime, prove that p divides $a^p +(p-1)!a$ and p divides $(p-1)!a^p +a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If p is prime, prove that p divides $a^p +(p-1)!a$ and p divides $(p-1)!a^p +a$

The answer is related to Fermat's Little theorem, but I can't figure out how to incorporate a factorial into the theorem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with Wilson's Theorem?

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Comment: You can factorize by $a$ to see a better form !

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

-- FLT: For any $\;a\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;a^p\equiv a\pmod p\;$

-- Wilson's Theorem: for any prime $\;p\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;(p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod p\;$

Comment: So p divides $a^p-a$ and p divides $(p-1)!+1$, so p divides their product. So p divides $a^p(p-1)!+a^p-a(p-1)!-a$. So p divides $a^p(p-1)!+a^p$ and p divides $a(p-1)!+a$ ?

Comment: FLT denotes Fermat's Little Theorem in this case. It could also stand for Fermat's Last Theorem.

Comment: Wait...if a number divides a number, can we say that it divides two numbers that sum up to that number? If 3 divides 18, 3 doesn't divide 1 and 17. So is the last sentence of my proof incorrect?

Comment: @DERPYPENGUIN I misread. The real reason is, doing arithmetic modulo $\;p\;$, that: $$a^p(p-1)!\equiv a(-1)\pmod p\;,\;\;a^p\equiv a\pmod p\;$$ so now you can add these two summands and get $\;0\pmod p\;$, and the smae with the other one.

Comment: To see a better form (to apply the two theorems) notice that : $a^p+(p-1)!a=a(a^{p-1}+(p-1)!)$ and $(p-1)!a^p+a=a((p-1)!a^{p-1}+1)$ ! Just use the compatibility by multiplication of $\pmod p$ !!